# How to load a new website which url is stored in an array every minute

Tags: javascript, php, cron

I need to load a different website to my browser every minute. The sites` urls are saved in an array.
I don't want to use the sleep function because it stops the script.
Currently the first page won't load. How do you do this with java script or with cron jobs?

```
<?php
$pages = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.amazon.de"];

foreach ($pages as $page) {
  header("Location: $page");
  sleep(5);
}
```

Actually it should load google.com and after a minute it should load amazon.com.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this but you could be using cron jobs for that if you want to do server side

Comment: Do you mean you want to load the page on client once and then every minute change dashboard contents?

Comment: There has to be a way to do this in PHP though. But i will check out cron jobs as well. Thank you.

Comment: I want to load a page from this array to my browser every minute.

Comment: @TonyTony PHP is a server-side language only. It cannot be executed over a long time span. It generates page upon request and it never comes back to the same request. What you need to look to instead is JavaScript.

Comment: use javascript to load pages, it can't be done using PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can't. HTTP doesn't work like that.

You can redirect from the requested URL to a different URL, but then the browser will have gone to the new URL and it will be too late to send a different redirect from the original URL.

The only way I can think of to do what you want it to display the cycling pages in a frame and use client-side JavaScript to change its `src` on an interval. That would only work if the pages being displayed didn't block framing with `X-Frame-Options` (which `http://www.google.com` does).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This can't be achieved only using PHP you have to use javascript to reload the page at client side 
Following code might help you, where you have te redirect to same page with array index and then loading webpage in iframe.

```
<?php
    $i = isset($_GET['index']) ? $_GET['index'] : 0;
    $pages = ["https://www.google.com", "https://www.amazon.de"];
    echo $i ."--". count($pages);
    if($i < count($pages)) {
?>
<iframe src="<?php echo $pages[$i];?>"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello");
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/reload.php?index=<?php echo ++$i;?>"; }, 30000);

</script>
<?php
} else {
    echo "All Done."
}
?>
```

Hope this helps you !!!

Comment: Yes that's true

Answer (score 0):

`PHP` is server side. It means that when client connects to your server with a browser, your `PHP` script generates a content to display and does it only once per request.

`Javascript` is client side. It means that your browser runs the script. But after changing url of the currently viewed site, you won't have any power on it, as it loads own `javascript` scripts (if there are any).

What You want to do could be achieved via `frames` (but the sites you have listed are not `frame` friendly, and they will redirect to itself anyway, so you will lose control on first load) or via browser `plugin`, that is more complicated and user would have to install the `plugin` first.